# Ubuntu 14.04 runs very slow on my PC.

Tags: 14.04

Ununtu is all new for me. 
I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 -32 Bit to my computer. Everything looks good but it's runs extremely slow.  As soon as I type something or I select anything first everything frizzes then slowly moves. Any video on YouTube I try to play it's going a frame by frame.  It's very bad. 
My PC is Intel Pentium 4 with 3.2GHz processor. 
3.5GB of Ram DDR
Hard drive is 160GB
Video card is a ATI Radeon 9250 I think with 64MB. 
This computer is from 2004, 12 years old. 
 Originally this computer had Windows XP. It was running grate. Then I installed Windows 7 but it was a  trial version. It wasn't that bad. 
But now with Ubuntu it is very very slow. Cannot be used. 
Please let me know what I should do?
Should I install a different OS?
If I have to change something in the settings please explain me in details how to do it  because I am a big stranger with Ubuntu. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, search for the app called additional drivers in the dash. Open it and wait for it to find any drivers, if it finds any then select any proprietary drivers as they are usually faster.  If nothing happens you should try a more lightweight version of Ubuntu like lubuntu or kubuntu.

Comment: Als restart your PC if any drivers are installed.

Comment: No luck with Ubuntu. I installed Lubuntu and now it's working fine. Just it's not quite like ubuntu  And I can't  have Chrome

Comment: You could get chromium, I believe it still has 32 bit support and its open source. Its in the software center, and its almost the same as Google chrome.